# lua - how to create functions

Tags: function, lua

I have a question about declaring functions in lua.

I was under the impression that public functions are declared as:

```
abc = function()
end
```

Local/private  functions as:

```
local abc = function
end
```

But I'm not sure what this notation is:

```
function abc()
end
```

Comment: There are no function *declarations* in Lua, only function *definitions*.

Comment: There are no public or private functions in Lua, only function values. Variables are either global or local and can reference any type of value, including functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen in 2.5.9 of the [reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html),

The statement

```
 function f () body end
```

translates to

```
 f = function () body end
```